# vim: replace all characters up to a given token

Tags: string, vim, replace

Using vim I would like to replace all characters up to a certain one with another character, say a blank space - *without* affecting the layout/number of characters in the line. Here's an example:

Before:

```
real(kind=R12), intent(out) :: my_var
```

After replacing `, intent(out)` with blanks (i.e. starting from `,`, and going up to `)`):

```
real(kind=R12)              :: my_var
```

I know about `r` to replace one character, and about `nr` to replace `n` characters, but I would like to know whether I can accomplish my task without first having to count the characters I want to replace.

Thanks a lot for your replies!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Visual mode is probably the shortest way here:

```
vt:r
```

- `v` enter visual mode
- `t:` select till `:`
- `r` (note space after `r`) replace selected region with spaces.

Comment: Just to note, you can use any motion, not just `t`. `f`,`/`, etc. all work too.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! I remembered doing this accidentally, so I knew what to search for. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to replace characters up to a given token *before* the cursor's current location?

Comment: @KayceBasques: I don't understand the question. Perhaps you should post it as a question? With more detail

Comment: Given the string `foo bar`, the cursor is on `r`, and I want to replace everything before it with `x`, stopping at `f`, so that the end result is `fxxxxxr`.

Comment: @KayceBasques: I would go with: `hvTfrx`

Answer (score 6):

In command mode type '**df**?' to delete up to that (?) character. Then '**i**' to go back to insert.

For example if the following sentence is in your view:

```
The wizard quickly jinxed the gnomes before they vaporized.
```

and you enter  **dfs**

You will be left with:

```
 before they vaporized.
```

Comment: note: **dts** will delete up until the s but leave the s.

Answer (score 3):

> I know about r to replace one character

Did you know that <kbd>R</kbd> will keep you in that replace mode? So you could hit <kbd>R</kbd> and then hold <kbd>Space</kbd> until you've replaced everything you want.

However, I'd still go with Thor's answer. Visual mode allows you to use the efficient text navigation methods in vim without having to count out characters.

But if you disagree, there's always [EasyMotion](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3526).

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression here (use `(.*?)` to reference all values up to a token).

For instance:

The regex: `(.*?)foo` will get rid of everything up to foo.

Comment: In perl maybe, in vim the non-greedy quantifier is `\{-}`.